# How to use variables from .ENV file in dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have 2 files, the first one is (`dockerfile`) and the second (`test.env`)
when I run the dockerfile I want it will takes the variable aaa which = to index.php from the test.env

dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.2.2-apache
ENV test.env ${aaa} 
COPY ${aaa} /var/www/html
```

test.env:

```
aaa='index.php'
```

any help would be appreciated
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It would not be possible to use it directly.
You may want to try this :

```
COPY test.env /
RUN export $(cat test.env | xargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can supply variables to be used at build stage as build arguments. Environment variables can be used by containers, but not to build images.

For your problem:

```
docker build $(sed 's/^/ --build-arg /g' test.env | xargs) -t <your_image_tag> .
```

If you have variables defined in test.env that are not declared as arguments (ARG) in Dockerfile you will get a warning.

Your Dockerfile should be:

```
FROM php:7.2.2-apache

ARG aaa

COPY ${aaa} /var/www/html
```

Answer (score -1):

You can define a variable in your Dockerfile:

```
ARG aaa='index.php'
ENV aaa=${aaa}
```

But if you want to use the ones from the external file you have, you can run your container this way:

```
docker run --env-file=test.env
```

Comment: Any reason for the downvote? I want to learn from my mistakes.

Comment: Mendel wants to copy a file at build time based on a variable that he can dynamically supply. At this stage environment variables are not available. COPY runs at build time, not at run time. I hope this clarifies but I can explain more if necessary.

Comment: @Mihai Totally clear. I misunderstood OP's intention.

Comment: thank you. so how my test.env file should looks like?    (aaa='index.php')

Comment: AND the docker run (docker run -d -p 80:80 --env-file test.env env)

Comment: `COPY ${aaa} /var/www/html` happends when do `docker build`, `docker run` to pass any env too late for the aim. I think @Mihai 's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/56721620/6394722 is correct.

Comment: docker run -d -p 80:80 --env-file test.env  ???  test.env(aaa='index.php')?? dockerfile (COPY ${aaa} /var/www/html)  ????